# Null input send to Oracle function

Tags: c#, oracle, function, input

I try to pass a parameter to my function but it is come as null. would you mind check and keep me posted what is wrong with my code?

```
string CommandStr = "BFN_HASH_PASSWORD";

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(CommandStr, conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("V_INPASSWD", OracleDbType.Varchar2,ParameterDirection.Input).Value ="TEST";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("V_OUTPASSWD", OracleDbType.Varchar2,ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("hash pass:"+ cmd.Parameters["V_OUTPASSWD"].Value.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("hash pass:" + cmd.Parameters["V_INPASSWD"].Value.ToString());
}
```

my oracle function:

```
FUNCTION BFN_HASH_PASSWORD(V_INPASSWD VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
        V_OUTPASSWD VARCHAR2(1000):= '';
        LN_CNT1 NUMBER := 0;
        LN_SUM  NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
        IF V_INPASSWD IS NOT NULL THEN
                LN_CNT1 := LENGTH(RTRIM(LTRIM(V_INPASSWD)));

                FOR I IN  1 .. LN_CNT1 LOOP
                        LN_SUM := LN_SUM + ASCII(SUBSTR(UPPER(V_INPASSWD),I,1)) ;
                END LOOP;
                V_OUTPASSWD := V_INPASSWD || LN_SUM;

                insert into TEST_CSHARP(msg,d_date) values('V_OUTPASSWD:'||V_OUTPASSWD,sysdate);
                commit;

                RETURN(V_OUTPASSWD);          
        ELSE                 
                insert into TEST_CSHARP(msg,d_date) values('V_INPASSWD:'||V_INPASSWD,sysdate);
                commit;
                RETURN V_INPASSWD; 
        END IF;
END ;
```

the output of test_csharp is as below:

> ```
>  msg          d_date
> ```
>
> V_INPASSWD:   05/03/2018 14:05:34

Comment: What does show up in the first message box?

Comment: Could you specify which OracleClient library you are using? The one now obsolete from .Net framework? Or one from Oracle? What specific version?

Comment: @Hilarion: I used Nuget, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 12.2.1100

Comment: it is empty like : "hash pass:"

Comment: Could you test what happens, when you also do the MessageBox.Show prior to executing the function?

Comment: I'd test using the `Add` overload, which allows you also to pass the parameter value, i.e.: `cmd.Parameters.Add("V_INPASSWD", OracleDbType.Varchar2,"TEST",ParameterDirection.Input);` instead of `cmd.Parameters.Add("V_INPASSWD", OracleDbType.Varchar2,ParameterDirection.Input).Value ="TEST";`.

Comment: @Hilarion: data is available, I put watch even parameter is contain the data

Comment: @Hilarion: as adviced by Mardukar, I already tested that one also as shown in below

Comment: @Hilarion: again tested with your solution, empty string is coming out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As adviced by Mardukar, I enabled the OracleCommand.bindByName = true and defined size of the varchar2 as shown in below. after that problem solved.

```
 string CommandStr = "BFN_HASH_PASSWORD";

            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(CommandStr, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.BindByName = true;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("V_INPASSWD",OracleDbType.Varchar2,ParameterDirection.Input);
                        cmd.Parameters["V_INPASSWD"].Value = "test";
                        cmd.Parameters["V_INPASSWD"].Size = 1000;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("V_OUTPASSWD", OracleDbType.Varchar2,ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
                        cmd.Parameters["V_OUTPASSWD"].Size = 1000;

                        conn.Open();

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        string output = (string)cmd.Parameters["V_OUTPASSWD"].Value.ToString();

                       MessageBox.Show("hash pass:"+ output);
                       MessageBox.Show("hash pass:" + cmd.Parameters["V_INPASSWD"].Value.ToString());
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to tell your parameter that it is an output parameter.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("V_INPASSWD", "TEST");
cmd.Parameters.Add("V_OUTPASSWD", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Comment: There is a problem in connecting to database!

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'BFN_HASH_PASSWORD'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
---------------------------

Comment: I tried like  this also but no diffrence:  cmd.Parameters.Add("V_INPASSWD", "TEST");
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("V_OUTPASSWD", OracleDbType.Varchar2,ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I thought you don't get a return value.

Comment: @Mardukar: With just one input parameter, using by-name binding should make no difference.